# XML Data into Row Selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a single field in a DB which contains columns of data, but in an continuous string of XML.
I want to extract the data from the XML, and return as normal columns.
There could be multiple rows of data within this single field.

Here are 2 real examples of data in this field

Example 1:

```
<DocumentElement>    
    <AuditTrailDetail>      
        <TableName>order_header_total</TableName>      
        <RowID>837</RowID>      
        <AuditType>Edit</AuditType>      
        <FieldName>oht_foreign_net</FieldName>     
        <ValueFrom>65.1600</ValueFrom>      
        <ValueTo>115.1600</ValueTo>      
        <EntityName />     
        <DisplayName />      
        <Identifier />    
    </AuditTrailDetail>   
    <AuditTrailDetail>     
        <TableName>order_line_item</TableName>     
        <RowID>2442</RowID>      
        <AuditType>Edit</AuditType>     
        <FieldName>oli_qty_required</FieldName>      
        <ValueFrom>1.0000</ValueFrom>     
        <ValueTo>2.0000</ValueTo>      
        <EntityName />      
        <DisplayName />      
        <Identifier>61 - test</Identifier>    
    </AuditTrailDetail>  
</DocumentElement>
```

Example 2:

```
<DocumentElement>   
    <AuditTrailDetail>      
        <TableName>order_line_item</TableName>      
        <RowID>2446</RowID>      
        <AuditType>Edit</AuditType>     
        <FieldName>oli_description</FieldName>      
        <ValueFrom>2 Ply Tissue Masks</ValueFrom>     
        <ValueTo>2 Ply Tissue Masksdd</ValueTo>      
        <EntityName />     
        <DisplayName />      
        <Identifier>D/D170 - 2 Ply Tissue Masksdd</Identifier>   
    </AuditTrailDetail>  
</DocumentElement>
```

For Example 1, I'd like to return 2 rows as below:

[image: example1]

For Example 2 there is one row, and I'd like it as below:

[image: Example2]

The fields in the table are:

```
owat_id
owat_audit_type
owat_record_id
owat_record_type
owat_datetime
owat_ud_id
owat_details
```

The XML data is within `owat_details`.

Assume the table name is `Audit_Trail`.

How can I do this directly in the SQL query?

Comment: Are you familiar with XQuery?  http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_example.asp

Comment: Not at all. I should have probably mentioned this should be done entirely in the SQL query.

Comment: XQuery is used within your sql query :)  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: you can use ado.net data table

Comment: You want read the special field that contain xml text then convert xml to sql table ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Johnie Karr

I have got this working using XQuery.

I have to do 2 queries and union them together to get the 2 separate elements in one field as separate rows. I'm sure there is a cleaner solution, but this works.

Thank you very much :)

```
SELECT 
AuditTrail.owat_record_type,
AuditTrail.owat_audit_type,
AuditTrail.owat_datetime as 'Audit Date',
user_detail.ud_username as 'User',
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/TableName)[1]','varchar(50)') AS TableName,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/RowID)[1]','varchar(50)') AS RowID,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/FieldName)[1]','varchar(50)') AS FieldName,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/ValueFrom)[1]','varchar(50)') AS ValueFrom,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/ValueTo)[1]','varchar(50)') AS ValueTo,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/Identifier)[1]','varchar(50)') AS Identifier
FROM 

    (select
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_id,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_audit_type,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_record_id,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_record_type,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_datetime,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_ud_id,
    convert(xml, orderwise_audit_trail.owat_details) as owat_details
    from
    orderwise_audit_trail) as AuditTrail

left join user_detail on user_detail.ud_id = AuditTrail.owat_ud_id  

Where AuditTrail.owat_details is not NULL
and (AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/TableName)[1]','varchar(50)')) is not null

UNION ALL

SELECT 
AuditTrail.owat_record_type,
AuditTrail.owat_audit_type,
AuditTrail.owat_datetime as 'Audit Date',
user_detail.ud_username as 'User',
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/TableName)[2]','varchar(50)') AS TableName,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/RowID)[2]','varchar(50)') AS RowID,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/FieldName)[2]','varchar(50)') AS FieldName,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/ValueFrom)[2]','varchar(50)') AS ValueFrom,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/ValueTo)[2]','varchar(50)') AS ValueTo,
AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/Identifier)[2]','varchar(50)') AS Identifier

FROM 

    (select
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_id,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_audit_type,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_record_id,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_record_type,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_datetime,
    orderwise_audit_trail.owat_ud_id,
    convert(xml, orderwise_audit_trail.owat_details) as owat_details
    from
    orderwise_audit_trail) as AuditTrail

left join user_detail on user_detail.ud_id = AuditTrail.owat_ud_id  

Where AuditTrail.owat_details is not NULL
and (AuditTrail.owat_details.value('(/DocumentElement/AuditTrailDetail/TableName)[2]','varchar(50)')) is not null

order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```